# In WPF how do I make textbox in main window update?

Tags: c#, wpf

So I setup a simple Textbox

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        DataContext="{Binding}" xmlns:Local="clr-namespace:MyProject">
    <TextBox Name="txb_userActivity" IsEnabled="False" IsReadOnly="True">
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="lastUserActivity">
            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
</Window>
```

I am trying to setup a Property:

```
namespace MyProject{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window{
        private DateTime _lastUserActivity = DateTime.Now;
        public DateTime lastUserActivity{
            set {
                _lastUserActivity = value;
            }
            get {
                return _lastUserActivity;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So that the Textbox will update it's value when the property is changed:

```
lastUserActivity = DateTime.Now;
```

My code isn't working, what should I do?

Comment: Any frameworks? You pointing to the right property?

Comment: I will update my code to show framework.

Comment: vanilla wpf then ... try @Herm answer, and make sure that the property name inside the `OnPropertyChanged` matches the name of the property (typos there lead to silent non updating bindings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your View needs a notification that it has to be updated.

You have to use either a `DependencyProperty`, or implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, then your setter should look something like

```
private DateTime _lastUserActivity = DateTime.Now; 
public DateTime LastUserActivity {
    set {
        _lastUserActivity = value;
    }
    get {
        return _lastUserActivity;
        OnPropertyChanged("LastUserActivity")
    }
}
```

Furthermore, you should use a ViewModel and do not use this Property in your codebehind of the Window. If you want your Binding to work you have to set a `DataContext` to this ViewModel. When you leave it in the codebehind you'd have to set your Window as `DataContext`.

edit:
for `DependencyObject`s you should use `DependencyProperty` like this:

```
// Dependency Property
public static readonly DependencyProperty LastUserActivityProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register( "LastUserActivity", typeof(DateTime),
    typeof(MainWindow), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(DateTime.Now));

// .NET Property wrapper
public DateTime LastUserActivity
{
    get { return (DateTime)GetValue(LastUserActivityProperty); }
    set { SetValue(LastUserActivityProperty, value); }
}
```

but again:
If you wish to use bindings, you should become familiar with MVVM principles and use a ViewModel instead of codebehind. Something like this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial

edit2:
your DataContext is wrong.

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" xmlns:Local="clr-namespace:MyProject">
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific?  OnPropertyChanged say it have some invalid arguments.

Comment: please check if your class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` like http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/41817/Implementing-INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: My class is the main window class that came with the project!  Does it still need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged ?  It is partial that implement Window.

Comment: The class `Window` is of type `DependencyObject`, you should use a `DependencyProperty` instead. I'll edit my post.

Comment: It's not updating txb_userActivity, are you the registrating is correct?  Nowhere does it refer to txb_userActivity, how will it know to update it?

Comment: you say it in the binding. what does it say in the output window, there should be a hint if your binding is correct, check for typo mistakes, too.